# ordering by a field in a foreign key alphabetically

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask assistance with this matter, I am trying to order the queryset of `Job_Posting` through `.order_by('fkey')` but I would like to order it alphabetically not by `foreign key`

```
class Job(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    Num_Positions = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):           
        return self.Job_Position



class Job_Posting(models.Model):

    fkey = models.ForeignKey("Job")
    Job_Description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
```

Via

`job_list = Job_Posting.objects.all().order_by('fkey')`

Expected results

- ajob(fkey 3)
- bjob(fkey 1)
- cjob(fkey 2)

My current results with `.order_by('fkey')`

- bjob(fkey 1)
- cjob(fkey 2)
- ajob(fkey 3)

Is it possible to list them alphabetically through `.order_by()` or there some other way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the foreign key do you want to order by? Job or Num positions? (Btw, fkey is a bad name for a field, num positions should be an integer field, and it would be better to reference the class rather than as a string)

Comment: Noted :), I would like to order the `Job_Posting`

Comment: Which model in your post holds the value `bjob`?

Comment: That would be under `Job` in `Job_Position`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I believe your initial answer was correct. Your welcome to take the contents from my answer if you wish (and I would delete mine also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Job_Posting.objects.order_by("fkey__Num_Positions")
```

or

```
Job_Posting.objects.order_by("fkey__Job_Position")
```

depending on which field from `Job` model you want to order by.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), when you order by a foreign key it is ordered by the id of that key (by default). Since you want to order by a field on that fk then you need to use `__` to denote the field name also

```
job_list = Job_Posting.objects..order_by('fkey__Job_Position')
```

Note: The `.all()` was also not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
job_list = Job_Posting.objects.order_by('fkey__Job_Position')
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

> To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when
>   you are querying across model relations. That is, the name of the
>   field, followed by a double underscore (__), followed by the name of
>   the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want
>   to join.